# Convert Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> to another List< Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, json

```
I have a JSON like below generatted by some external API 
    {
        "0": {
            "0": "Qty",
            "1": "Code",
            "2": "Description",
            "3": "Unit",
            "4": "Net"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "24",
            "1": "42097805",
            "2": "R Ball -G   - Red",
            "3": "8.85",
            "4": "212.40"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": "5",
            "1": "32037405",
            "2": "K Ball -G - Blue",
            "3": "8.85",
            "4": "212.40"
        },
        "3": {
            "0": "12",
            "1": "22192825",
            "2": "X Ball -G",
            "3": "8.85",
            "4": "212.40"
        }
        
    }
```

But while performing DeserializeObject , the Index values are not mapped correctly as the strings are dynamic in nature ["0" ,"1",....etc

From comments using  Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>  helps to complete the DeserializeObject

To represent them visually i have to convert to another model which is like below  List<Dictionary<string, string>>

```
    =>
    
     
        {
            "0": "Qty",
            "1": "Code",
            "2": "Description",
            "3": "Unit",
            "4": "Net"
        },
        {
            "0": "24",
            "1": "42097805",
            "2": "R Ball -G   - Red",
            "3": "8.85",
            "4": "212.40"
        },
        {
            "0": "5",
            "1": "32037405",
            "2": "K Ball -G - Blue",
            "3": "8.85",
            "4": "212.40"
        },
        {
            "0": "12",
            "1": "22192825",
            "2": "X Ball -G",
            "3": "8.85",
            "4": "212.40"
        }
```

Can i convert the Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>  to    List<Dictionary<string, string>> without looping

Comment: deserialize to `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `System.Text.Json` or `Json.Net` to handle json you can deserialize such dynamic structure to nested dictionaries (`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`). For exmaple for latter one it will look like this:

```cs
string json = ....
var deserializeObject = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
```

Comment: Deserialization will work with this. How about the conversion of dictionary  items to a list of dictionary without looping? Can we make it with help of LINQ

Comment: @Sebastian can you please explain waht is needed in a little bit more detail?

Comment: Editted further and hopefully it is explaining the need

Comment: @Sebastian TBH it is separate question, but in general it should be as easy as smth like `deserializeObject.Values.ToList()`